# Cannot use connection to Gradle distribution 'xxxx' as it has been stopped

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, forge

so I have never had this happen before, I am trying to load a gradle project in IntelliJ idea, but I keep getting this following error.

```
Cannot use connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip' as it has been stopped.
```

Here is the logs of the gradle process

```
Download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip finished, took 14 s 732 ms (69.3 MB)
7:49:01 AM: Execution finished 'wrapper'.
```

Could not find anything on google that was useful.

Comment: still looking for a solution that could work with gradle 3.0

Comment: Does it work fine from command line outside IDE?

Comment: When it says "Cannot use connection to Gradle distribution 'xxxx' as it has been stopped" I simply closed the project, quit android studio, and then relaunched Android Studio and opened the project and it worked, i.e., Gradle was not stopped and I could continue.

Answer (score 4):

When it says "Cannot use connection to Gradle distribution 'xxxx' as it has been stopped" I simply closed the project, quit android studio, and then relaunched Android Studio and opened the project and it worked, i.e., Gradle was not stopped and I could continue.

Answer (score 3):

I just clicked **Reload Gradle Project** as shown in the picture and the issue is gone.

[image]